# Тыльный - the rear, back or other side?

Tags: перевод, значения, выбор-слова

I'm mostly familiar with тыл in the military sense - "rear of the battle" or "the home front".

However I recently encountered the phrase "Тыльная сторона руки".  Which I understood to mean the back of the hand.

Questions:

1. In what other collocations, idioms, or constructions is тыл or тыльный used?
2. Can "Тыльная сторона руки" be used in the English idiom "like the back of my hand"?
   http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/know+like+the+back+of+hand
   .  Or does it only work with "как свои пять пальцев."
3. When would you use "тыльный" instead of "задний"?

Comment: It's not `тыль`, it's `тыл`.

Comment: right you are - fixed

Comment: Затылок и подзатыльник тоже от этого корня.

Comment: "Тыльная сторона руки" (more correct is "тыльная сторона ладони", because **рука** is an **arm**) means "back side of a hand (opposite to a palm)". Also this phrase cannot be use like the English idiom "like the back of my hand". It can be translated only as "как свои пять пальцев".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Тыльный* means "back end" (as opposed to "business end"), the side or end you don't normally use or see:

> - Сейчас в продаже появились зубные щётки, тыльная поверхность головки которых имеет специальную резиновую подушечку для чистки языка.
> - Затем взять канцелярскую кнопку, немного загнуть острие, тыльную сторону обезжирить, смазать клеем и плотно прижать к стене.
> - Бодро открываю капот и направляю луч карманного фонарика на тыльную сторону фары.

*Тыл* can be used as a synonym to *зад* (as you mentioned, primarily in the military context, but also as a joke or a euphemism):

> - К выходу альбома «Encore» Эм побрил пятую точку и принял ответственное решение сняться «ню» ― правда, только с тыла.